# Selfi-Kiosk with Kweb and Camera - how to show preview image

Tags: camera, php

I use the Kweb browser to boot in kiosk mode and would like to build an interface, where people can take selfis.

I use HTML and jquery for the frontend and php to do shell-exec commands like starting and stopping the camera.

How do I get the camera preview image to be shown in advance to the user? Can I stream it in the browser?

I'm just beginning, should I use a complete different approach?